# JConsole display attribute value in a spreadsheet

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, mbeans

I have found a screenshot of JConsole at http://doc.algotrader.ch/html/Client.html and it suprised me that it's able to present attribute values as a spreadsheet. Does anyone know what magic is required here? I guess it not a standard jconsole/jmx feature...

I don't have enough reputation point to post images, so just scroll down to the first image following the link above and look the attribute DataBalances.

Answer (score 0):

It's collection of BalanceVO.

Check [ManagementService](http://doc.algotrader.ch/javadoc/ch/algotrader/service/ManagementService.html)

Comment: Thanks, I 've found this javadoc too. I tried to return a collection of simple JavaBean as they do. After putting my JavaBean class on the classpath of JConsole it only showed the toString() of collection... So it did not display it in table format.

Comment: I think there are some rules what you can expose. You can start with java.io.Serializable and also collection which you return should also implement Serializable.

Comment: Correct wihtout implementing the java.io.Serializable exception is thrown. But even if I made my class Serializable it did not shown as table.